# Casting an Array Object

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

My requirement is to `Clone` an array `Object`. This is the kind of code I am using:

```
        Array numbers = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), 10);
        index = 0;
        foreach (int x in numbers)
        {
            numbers.SetValue(index * index, index);
            index++;
        }
        Object numberClone = numbers.Clone();
```

Now, how do I cast the `Object` numberClone to `Array` of intergers?

Comment: At first glance, have you tried this: int[] arrayOfInt = (int[])numberClone; ?

Comment: Why don't just use ArrayList ?

Comment: Array numberClone = (Array)numbers.Clone(); Tried this?

Comment: @bytefire, I did just that! Thanks. `Array numberClone = (int [])numberClone;` worked!

Comment: So you already know at compile time that's an `int[]`? Why do you use `CreateInstance` at all then instead of something like this: `var newNums = new List<int>(numbers);
int[] newNumArray = newNums.ToArray();`?

Comment: No probs TheSilverBullet :)

Comment: @scheien, yours is the best solution and it worked. Would you mind posting it as answer so that I can mark it?

Comment: @TheSilverBullet Sure thing. It's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Array numbers = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), 10);
int index = 0;
foreach (int x in numbers)
{
    numbers.SetValue(index * index, index);
    index++;
}
Array numberClone = (Array)numbers.Clone();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using .net 3.5 this might help you

```
object[] objarr = new object[] {1,2,3 };
 int[] arr= objarr.Cast<int>().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Array numbers = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), 10);
           int index = 0;
            foreach (int x in numbers)
            {
                numbers.SetValue(index * index, index);
                index++;
            }
            Object numberClone = numbers.Clone();

            Array castNumbers = (Array)numberClone;

            foreach(int x in castNumbers)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(x);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Object numberClone = numbers.Clone();
var arr = numberClone as Array;
var listOfInt = arr.OfType<int>().Select(c => c).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not setting the same value in the foreach?

like this

```
int[] numbers = new int[10]();
int[] numberClone = new int[10]();

foreach(var x in numbers)
{
nubmers[index*index] = index;
numberClone[index*index] = index;
}
```

Something like this i did this without VS so sorry if its wrong :P